# Java XML read problem: read different child tags

Tags: java, xml

Can someone tell me how to read this kind of XML file to get the child element names?

```
 <CEB>
    <MOREVALUES></MOREVALUES>
 </CEB>

 <DILOG>
    <MOREVALUES></MOREVALUES>
 </DILOG>

 <MOBITLE>
    <MOREVALUES></MOREVALUES>
 </MOBITLE>
```

e.g I want to read all the child tags inside the `<CTLBILL>` tag. `<CEB>`,  `<DILOG>`, and `<MOBITLE>` in this case.

This doesn't work:

```
public static void getTags() {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new File("C:\\ctlbill.xml"));
            NodeList nodeLst = doc.getChildNodes();
            for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++)
            {           
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Good formatting is your friend Aruna..

Comment: Thanks Sener Gonul... Thanks for the help ...

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? nodeLst is empty, or nodeLst.item(i) returns not what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
NodeList nodeLst = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++)
    if (nodeLst.item(s) instanceof Element)
        System.out.println(nodeLst.item(s).getNodeName());
```

I am assuming that CTLBILL is your document (root) element that contains CEB, DILOG and MOBITLE elements (well formed XML must have only one root element).

Comment: Thsnks for the help buddy... :) NodeList nodeLst = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes(); This is what I was missing.. Thanks a lot..